# Can a virtual printer application be installed using Desktop Bridge?

Tags: desktop-bridge

My Windows 10 application needs to install a virtual printer during installation. However I found no relevant options for it either in package manifest schema or in Desktop App Converter switches. I ran my application installation through Desktop App Converter but it did not capture virtual printer installation. Hence comes the question in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you want is called prerequisites and here is what have wrote in the official doc [Prepare to package an app (Desktop Bridge)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare)：

“Your app installation requires user interaction. Your app installer must be able to run silently, and it must install all of its prerequisites that aren't on by default on a clean OS image.”

If you need your app can use desktopbridge, please think about put the installation page in your app. Ask your customer to install this package after they've installed your app, like put it in your welcome page and tell your customer they need to install the printer before use your software.

Answer (score 0):

There's the `windows.appPrinter` app extension: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-desktop2-appprinter

Comment: Yes, I've seen this documentation page before but I don't know how to apply it to my case. There seems to be not much documentation available on "software file printers". I have a Windows GDI printer driver that is installed by existing installation program. How do I migrate printer installation procedure to make it compatible with Windows 10 and Desktop Bridge?

Comment: @arty The extension is used to register your app as the printer target. Not to install a single package.